# OpenSSL [des-ede3-cbc] encrypt php IV

Tags: php, encryption, php-openssl

I need to encrypt with PHP the data to send to a company.
They say I have to use my key and this IV:

```
{(byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x02}
```

They work in Java and sent me this snippet:

```
private static final IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec (new byte []
{(byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x02});
```

How can I turn it into PHP?
I tried like this: `$iv = pack("nvc*", 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x01, 0x02);` and I get the following error: Warning: openssl_encrypt (): IV passed is 10 bytes long which is longer than the 8 expected by selected cipher, truncating, if instead I put "H *" as a parameter it tells me that there are 7 unused arguments.
How can I transform it?
Thanks

Comment: The encryption method is DES-EDE3-CBC

Comment: `pack('n*', 0x0102, 0x0304, 0x0506, 0x0102);` seems to work

Comment: `pack("c*", 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x01, 0x02);` work too.
What will be the correct way?

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the **hex2bin**-function for a hexstring conversion to binary data.

Below you find a full encryption-decryption example with your algorithm "DES-EDE3-CBC".

This is the result:

```
OpenSSL [des-ede3-cbc] encrypt php IV
decrypted: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

**Security warning: the program has no exception handling and is for educational purpose only.**

code:

```
<?php
echo 'OpenSSL [des-ede3-cbc] encrypt php IV' . PHP_EOL;
$plaintext = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
$algorithm = "DES-EDE3-CBC";
$key = "123456789012345678901234";
$ivHex = hex2bin("0102030405060102");
// encryption
$encrypted = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $algorithm, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $ivHex);
// decryption
$decrypted = openssl_decrypt($encrypted, $algorithm, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $ivHex);
echo 'decrypted: ' . $decrypted . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Comment: There are always many ways to get the "correct" result and the method depends on your workflow. The "pack("c*" function is better if you receive the data from somewhere else to convert it back to data. The "hex2bin" way is good if you have a static hexstring that simply needs to get converted. If possible kindly mark my answer as "accepted" one, thanks in advance.